# How to write struct to file

Tags: c

So I am fairly new to c and would like to write a struct to a file so it is human readable, I don't have to reopen and read from this file.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
uint64_t lol[8] = {125,95687445,54778,84585,5745,45874,845,1111};
Cool ben = {.name = 
"vOWRrwxCzuEyishGjHkVKboNBMUdIfhTJZLqeAgDPFcQYSatnm", .other= *lol, 
.args = 1};
 writeToFile(& ben);

return 0;
```

}

```
typedef struct {

uint64_t other[8];
uint8_t args;
char name[40];
} Cool;

void writeToFile(Cool* reading){
char * filename = "anicename";
Cool ben = * reading;
FILE * open;
open= fopen(filename,"wt");
if (open== NULL ){
    exit (-1);
}

fwrite (&ben.name , sizeof(char),sizeof(ben.function_name),open);
fwrite (&ben.other , sizeof(uint64_t),sizeof(ben.arguments),open);
fwrite (&ben.args , sizeof(uint64_t),1,open);

fclose (opening);
}
```

I would also want it to create a new file if name doesn't exist and if the name exists that it doesn't overwrite the file but appends the existing file. The arrays aren't always full so I don't want it to print the null pointers into the file.
this gives

vOWRrwxCzuEyishGjHkVKboNBMUdIfhTJZLqeAgDPFcQYSatnm}                                                                             úLöý  àýf     I@     €ýf     gðïøý  8     LA9K    vOWRrwxCzuEyishGjHkVKboNBMUdIfhTJZLqeAgDPFcQYSatnm      }                                                                      }       ´    úÕ      iJ     q      2³      M      W      v@     À           ø@                  €y@                                                                                                                             xz´N3

so not realy usefull
Thx for helping

Comment: Presumably the file isn't human readable as-is.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: does `anicename` have an extension type?  if so, what is it?

Comment: Doesn't look like the code you show is compilable (for example where is variable `opening` declared?), even without the includes it obviously needs. If you want help 'why doesn't this code work?' you need to post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example see https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve because otherwise you will get Close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> write a struct to a file so it is human readable,

Write each `struct` member as clear text.  Possible with a tagged structure like format.

```
fprintf(open, "(Cool\n";
fprintf(open, "  (other"
for (i = 0; i< 8; i++) {
  fprintf(open, " %" PRIu64, ben.other[i]);
} 
fprintf(open, ")\n");
fprintf(open, "  (args %" PRIu8 ")\n", ben.args);
fprintf(open, "  (name \"%.*s\")\n", (int) sizeof ben.name, ben.name);
fprintf(open, ")\n";
```

Additional code could distinctively handle special characters in `.name` like non-printable ones, `"`, `)`, etc.